# exsisting URL parameters to flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can i get a url value without showing parameter string

sitename.com/example.swf?var1=[regionvar]

Swf used inside a virtual grid and above url string using var1=[regionvar]

does output the region instance number using this code

```
regionvar:String = loaderInfo.loaderURL;

text1.text = regionvar.toString()
```

the above returns

sitename.com/example.swf?var1=12345678

What i need is the value without including the parameter string in the url

sitename.com/example.swf

Being able to check the value of the region without parameter string in url

is needed to check if swf is being used only in the proper region.

regionvar is preexisting variable in grid

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var UV:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loaderInfo.loaderURL.split("?")[1]);

trace(UV['var1']);
```

**P.S.** Also try this, it just could work:

```
trace(loaderInfo.parameters['var1']);
```

Comment: Ty will try this and you have no idea how much it helps